# Recorrer Json dinamico php

Tags: php, json, datatables

Buenas necesito de su ayuda tengo un json que lo manipulo de forma dinámica y lo quiero mostrar en una tabla, estoy ocupando el plugin datatables

el json contiene detalles de productos que pueden cambiar dinámicamente, lo que hago es convertir el json a un array con json_decode y luego los recorre con un foreach para obtener su key y value

```
                //TRAER DETALLES
                //$productos[$i]["detalles"] estoy trayendo el json de la base de datos
                //el json es: {"Talla": [36,38,40],"Color": ["rojo","negro","blanco"],
                //"Marca":null
                }
                //
                $detalles = json_decode($productos[$i]["detalles"],true);


                foreach ($detalles as $key => $value) {
                $nombreDetalle = $key;
                $valorDetalle = json_encode($value);


                $vistaDetalles = ($nombreDetalle.": ". str_replace(array("[","]",'"'), "", $valorDetalle)." - ");
                echo $vistaDetalles;
```

al momento de imprimir los detalles dentro foreach no funciona como corresponde porque se me duplica el data de la tabla y  no se como arreglarlo

```
                $datosJson .='[
                            "'.($i+1).'",
                            "'.$vistaDetalles.'",
                            ],';
                echo $datosJson;
                }
```

Resultado:

```
            {
            "data":[[
                            "1",
                            "Talla: 36,38,40 - ",
                            ],
        {
            "data":[[
                            "1",
                            "Talla: 36,38,40 - ",
                            ],[
                            "1",
                            "Color: rojo,negro,blanco - ",
                            ],
        {
            "data":[[
                            "1",
                            "Talla: 36,38,40 - ",
                            ],[
                            "1",
                            "Color: rojo,negro,blanco - ",
                            ],[
                            "1",
                            "Marca: null - ",
                            ],
        {
```

y si lo imprimo fuera del foreach sale esto

```
"data":[[
                            "1",
                            "Talla: 36,38,40 - ",
                            ],[
                            "1",
                            "Color: rojo,negro,blanco - ",
                            ],[
                            "1",
                            "Marca: null - ",
                            ],
```

y lo que realmente quiero y no me sale, por eso acudo acá por su ayuda es

```
"data":[[
                            "1",
                            "Talla: 36,38,40 - Color: rojo,negro,blanco - Marca: null -",
                            ]
```

gracias y se lo agradecería un montan si me ayudan :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice este ejemplo con un string JSON

```
$json = '{"Talla": [36,38,40],"Color": ["rojo","negro","blanco"],"Marca":null}';
```

Creo una variable para guardar el resultado más adelante.

```
$response = [
    'data' => []
];
```

Obtengo el array asociativo apartir del JSON

```
$detalles = json_decode($json, true);
```

Creo una variable contador, y convierto el array **$detalles** en **indexado** con **[$detalles]**, para luego recorrer y formar lo que se desea.

```
$i = 1;
foreach ([$detalles] as $key => $value) {
    $vistaDetalles = '';
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        $nombreDetalle  = $k;
        $valorDetalle = json_encode($v);
        $vistaDetalles .= ($nombreDetalle.": ". str_replace(array("[","]",'"'), "", $valorDetalle)." - ");
    }
    $response['data'][] = [
        $i,
        $vistaDetalles
    ];
    $i++;
}
```

Fuera del foreach muestro el resultado

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($response);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Genial amigo, te pasaste 10+ gracias por el aporte :)